# Permission issue and step count for integrating samsung health in React Native application

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

I am working on React Native application. And i want to integrate Samsung health with the application but due to some permissions issues, i am unable to get proceed further and unable to get stepcount. Please help me out for the solution for this.

Comment: As far as I know, Samsung does not like it when you try to use that Samsung Health stuff

Answer (score 1):

Have a try to use the [rn-samsung-health](https://github.com/GaneshSinghPapola/rn-samsung-health#readme) npm package to get the steps count from the Samsung health.

Comment: But i also want to use it for ios also. and this library work for android only i guess.

Comment: You can check out the official Samsung docs I think there is no SDK from Samsung for the ios capability. https://developer.samsung.com/health

Comment: then what about this library - "react-native-samsung-health-android" it provides for both platform- android as well as ios?

Comment: No, no one library will provide the access to ios as the official Samsung doesn't provide the SDK for the ios platform.